# ANOVA, does "equal population variances" mean the same as "a single population"?

Tags: anova, heteroscedasticity

In ANOVA the assumption is made that the population variances of the different groups are the same. Assuming $H_0$ is correct, all population means are also the same. In this case, would it not be easier to simply assume that all observations come from the same single population? I do not see how this makes a difference in calculation, but conceptually a single population is easier to imagine and work with. Did I miss something?

Comment: I don't really understand what you ask about. Could uou clarify?  But see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76151/what-is-an-intuitive-explanation-of-why-we-want-homoskedasticity-in-a-regression/409074#409074

Comment: "Come from the same single population" will work but is (far) more restrictive unless you also assume all distributions are Normal.

Comment: @whuber: and the normal distribution assumption is not always made? (I implicitly assumed it is.)

Comment: It is rare for the Normal distribution assumption to hold exactly.  What matters is that the *sampling distributions* of the ANOVA statistics be close enough to their reference distributions (usually F ratio distributions) to produce reliable p-values. This permits a (much) broader application of ANOVA than would otherwise be possible.